# Downloaded project .xib file cannot open in XCode 4.6.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I downloaded FlickrKit and open its sample project file. But cannot run coz of following error. Changing the 'Deployment Target' didn't work.  Please, help !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error, the project was probably made in a newer version of Xcode than the one currently on your machine. Update your software and if it still doesn't work, I'd assume it was made with the newest developer only version, Xcode 5.

If this is the case you must purchase a developer account at the: [iPhone Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone) and download Xcode 5. If you do not want to do that, you cannot use the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Its easier than that to recover your existing project. Open the project file on Xcode 5. Then:**

1. Open file inspector for each xib
2. On "Interface Builder Documents" section change "Open with" to Xcode
   4.6 (if it's 5.0). Adjust any other obviously incompatible parameters
3. Save, Close the project and open with the old Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! But how to do the same for multiple xib files?